# Python Tkinter: adding a scrollbar to frame within a canvas

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter, scrollbar, tkinter-canvas

I am quite new to Tkinter, but, nevertheless, I was asked to "create" a simple form where user could provide info about the status of their work (this is sort of a side project to my usual work).
Since I need to have quite a big number of text widget (where users are required to provide comments about status of documentation, or open issues and so far), I would like to have something "scrollable" (along the y-axis).

I browsed around looking for solutions and after some trial and error I found something that works quite fine. 
Basically I create a canvas, and inside a canvas a have a scrollbar and a frame. Within the frame I have all the widgets that I need.

This is a snipet of the code (with just some of the actual widgets, in particular the text ones):

```
from Tkinter import *
## My frame for form
class simpleform_ap(Tk):
    # constructor
    def __init__(self,parent):
        Tk.__init__(self,parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.initialize()
    #
    def initialize(self):
    #
        self.grid_columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
        self.grid_rowconfigure(0,weight=1)
        #
        self.canvas=Canvas(self.parent)
        self.canvas.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky='nsew')
        #
        self.yscrollbar = Scrollbar(self,orient=VERTICAL)
        self.yscrollbar.grid(column =4, sticky="ns")
        #
        self.yscrollbar.config(command=self.canvas.yview)
        self.yscrollbar.pack(size=RIGTH,expand=FALSE)
        #
        self.canvas.config(yscrollcommand=self.yscrollbar.set)
        self.canvas.pack(side=LEFT,expand=TRUE,fill=BOTH)
        #
        self.frame1 = Frame(self.canvas)
        self.canvas.create_window(0,0,window=self.frame1,anchor='nw')
        # Various Widget        
        # Block Part
        # Label
        self.labelVariableIP = StringVar()  # Label variable
        labelIP=Label(self.frame1,textvariable=self.labelVariableIP,
                     anchor="w",
                     fg="Black")
        labelIP.grid(column=0,row=0,columnspan=1,sticky='EW')
        self.labelVariableIP.set(u"IP: ")
        # Entry: Single line of text!!!!
        self.entryVariableIP =StringVar()  # variable for entry field
        self.entryIP =Entry(self.frame1,
                            textvariable=self.entryVariableIP,bg="White")
        self.entryIP.grid(column = 1, row= 0, sticky='EW')
        self.entryVariableIP.set(u"IP")
        # Update Button or Enter
        button1=Button(self.frame1, text=u"Update",
                       command=self.OnButtonClickIP)
        button1.grid(column=2, row=0)
        self.entryIP.bind("<Return>", self.OnPressEnterIP)
        #...
        # Other widget here
        #
        # Some Text
        # Label
        self.labelVariableText = StringVar()  # Label variable                
        labelText=Label(self.frame1,textvariable=
                        self.labelVariableText,
                 anchor="nw",
                 fg="Black")
    labelText.grid(column=0,row=curr_row,columnspan=1,sticky='EW')
    self.labelVariableTexta.set(u"Insert some texts: ")
    # Text
    textState = TRUE
    self.TextVar=StringVar()
    self.mytext=Text(self.frame1,state=textState,
                     height = text_height, width = 10,
                     fg="black",bg="white") 
    #
    self.mytext.grid(column=1, row=curr_row+4, columnspan=2, sticky='EW')
    self.mytext.insert('1.0',"Insert your text")
    #
    # other text widget here
    #
    self.update()
    self.geometry(self.geometry() )
    self.frame1.update_idletasks()
    self.canvas.config(scrollregion=(0,0,
                       self.frame1.winfo_width(),
                       self.frame1.winfo_height()))
#
def release_block(argv):

    # Create Form
    form = simpleform_ap(None)
    form.title('Release Information')
    #
    form.mainloop()
#

if __name__ == "__main__":
  release_block(sys.argv)
```

As I mentioned before, this scripts quite does the work, even if, it has a couple of small issue that are not "fundamental" but a little annoying.

When I launch it I got this (sorry for the bad screen-capture):
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sjcZ4.png)

As it can be seen, it only shows up the first "column" of the grid, while I would like to have all them (in my case they should be 4)
To see all of the fields, I have to resize manually (with the mouse) the window.
What I would like to have is something like this (all 4 columns are there):
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DRRVA.png)

Moreover, the scrollbar does not extend all over the form, but it is just on the low, right corner of the windows.

While the latter issue (scrollbar) I can leave with it, the first one is a little more important, since I would like to have the final user to have a "picture" of what they should do without needing to resize the windows.

Does any have any idea on how I should proceed with this?
What am I missing?

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: In your `__init__`, you do not appear to have set the size of your main window. You should do that, or it will just set the window to a default size, which will only show whatever it can, and in your case, only 1 column. Therefore, in the `__init__` part of the class, try putting `self.geometry(str(your_width) + "x" + str(your_height))` where `your_width` and `your_height` are whatever integers you choose that allow you to see what you need to in the window.

Comment: I will make this, including a solution to your second problem, an answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot!
I manage to have it work and you made my day! 
I will wait for your final answer with also the second issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `__init__` method of your class, you do not appear to have set the size of your main window. You should do that, or it will just set the window to a default size, which will only show whatever it can, and in your case, only 1 column. Therefore, in the `__init__` method, try putting `self.geometry(str(your_width) + "x" + str(your_height))` where `your_width` and `your_height` are whatever integers you choose that allow you to see what you need to in the window.

As for your scrollbar issue, all I had to do was change the way your scrollbar was added to the canvas to a `.pack()` and added the attributes `fill = 'y' and side = RIGHT` to it, like so:

```
self.yscrollbar.pack(side = 'right', fill = 'y')
```

Also, you don't need:

```
self.yscrollbar.config(command=self.canvas.yview)
self.yscrollbar.pack(size=RIGHT,expand=FALSE)
```

Just add the command option to the creation of the scrollbar, like so:

```
self.scrollbar = Scrollbar(self,orient=VERTICAL,command=self.canvas.yview)
```

In all, the following changes should make your code work as expected:

- Add:

  ```
  def __init__(self,parent):
      Tk.__init__(self,parent)
      self.parent = parent
      self.initialize()
      # Resize the window from the default size to make your widgets fit. Experiment to see what is best for you.
      your_width = # An integer of your choosing
      your_height = # An integer of your choosing
      self.geometry(str(your_width) + "x" + str(your_height))
  ```
- Add and Edit:

  ```
  # Add `command=self.canvas.yview`
  self.yscrollbar = Scrollbar(self,orient=VERTICAL,command=self.canvas.yview)
  # Use `.pack` instead of `.grid`
  self.yscrollbar.pack(side = 'right', fill = 'y')
  ```
- Remove:

  ```
  self.yscrollbar.config(command=self.canvas.yview)
  self.yscrollbar.pack(size=RIGHT,expand=FALSE)
  ```